# How to get warning message if a folder exists?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to check if the folder Import Templates is present in the folder the main workbook is saved in.

If it is, display a message advising to rename or delete the folder as needed.
If the folder does not exist there is code to create the folder and export the sheets in the workbook into that folder.

If the folder doesn't exist the code runs perfectly, if it does exist the warning message does not pop up and displays

> run time error #75

```vb
Private Sub ExportSheets()       'saves all visible sheets as new xlsx files
Dim ws As Worksheet, wbNew As Workbook
Dim sFolderPath As String
Dim fs As Object
Set wbNew = Application.ThisWorkbook
sFolderPath = wbNew.Path & "\" & "Import Templates"
If Dir(sFolderPath) <> "" Then
'If the folder does exist
    MsgBox "The folder currently exists, please rename or delete the folder!", vbInformation, "Import Files"
Else
'If the folder does not exist available
MkDir sFolderPath
End If
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets                      'for each worksheet
    If ws.visible Then                                  'if it's visible:
        Debug.Print "Exporting: " & ws.Name
        ws.Copy '(if no params specified, COPY creates + activates a new wb)
        Set wbNew = Application.ActiveWorkbook          'get new wb object
        wbNew.SaveAs sFolderPath & "\" & ws.Name & ".csv", 23 'save new wb
        wbNew.Close                                     'close new wb
        Set wbNew = Nothing                             'cleanup
    End If
Next ws
Set ws = Nothing                                        'clean up
End Sub
```

Comment: is wbNew saved at this point?  WHat is the value of `sFolderPath`

Comment: The code will create a new folder within the current folder the workbook is saved in. So if I save the workbook in C:\Downloads it creates a new folder in C:\Downloads\Import Templates.

Comment: Yes, but .path only exists when it's saved.

Comment: `Dir(sFolderPath, vbDirectory)` if you're checking for a folder.  And presumably you should `Exit Sub` after the messagebox if the folder already exists.

Comment: Tim Williams, This worked perfectly. I cannot thank you enough!

Comment: If your question has been answered, I recommend placing your solution down as an answer for other future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If checking for a folder you need to use `vbDirectory`

```
Dir(sFolderPath, vbDirectory)
```

The default is `vbNormal`, which only returns files.

And presumably you should `Exit Sub` after the messagebox if the folder already exists.